# cannot generate classes with JAXB

Tags: jaxb

i try to generate classes using JAXB but I a get an exception :
     IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'g'
I'using a complex XSD file and a binding file as below.
Can somebody give a clue to where investigate ?

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
           xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="IFX170_XSD.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="cy.com.netinfo.netteller.ifx"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings> 
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="RemitDetail_Type.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="cy.com.netinfo.netteller.ifx.remitdetailinfo"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings> 
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="$pain.001.001.01.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="cy.com.netinfo.netteller.ifx.swift.pain_001_001_1"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings> 
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="$pain.002.001.01.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="cy.com.netinfo.netteller.ifx.swift.pain_002_001_1"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings> 
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="$pain.004.001.01.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="cy.com.netinfo.netteller.ifx.swift.pain_004_001_1"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings> 
        </jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: How are you calling xjc (arguments) and what is the schema?

Comment: It looks like annox uses 'g' as a namespace prefix in their examples.  Are you sure you've defined this namespace at the top of your schema?

Comment: Hi tdrury here are the namespace declaration for the 5 xsd files :
     <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.ifxforum.org/RemitDetailInfo/2004/07" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.ifxforum.org/RemitDetailInfo/2004/07" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

Comment: sorry this is the right one. Hi tdrury here is the namespace declaration for the main xsd file :
     <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:remit="http://www.ifxforum.org/RemitDetailInfo/2004/07" xmlns:pain001="urn:swift:xsd:$pain.001.001.01" xmlns:pain002="urn:swift:xsd:$pain.002.001.01" xmlns:pain004="urn:swift:xsd:$pain.004.001.01">  I'd like to show the whole xsd stuff but all 5 xsds are quite 800kb. I don't know how can I post them.

Comment: and this is the command I use : C:\deda\JAXB\jaxb-ri-20120516\bin\xjc.bat -d C:\deda\JAXB\ifx-src  -xmlschema C:\deda\JAXB\IFX170_XSD.xsd -b C:\deda\JAXB\binding.xjb

Comment: If you are missing the 'g' namespace definition then it's going to fail the first time it sees an element like <g:annox ..../>.  Do you see xmlns:g="http://..." in the header anywhere?

Comment: I created a package for jaxb 2.2.6 that includes patch for problem mentioned. Can be downloaded here: https://mega.co.nz/#!g4cmhTTT!Fkm2IBwOXO19PR64gVzUJHvfkBhdSQW5WY7YS5T5A4A

Answer (score 2):

At last I found the answer.
The problem is due to a mistake in the class Options in the package com.sun.tools.xjc.
In the method getPrologComment the class builds a localized message taking parameter fot date and time from a localized resource bundle, but then formats the date using a fixed Locale.ENGLISH. This behavior is inside JAXB 2.2.6.
I solved the problem simply updating the file MessageBundle_it.properties (in my case for italian) in the package com\sun\tools\xjc\ of the jar file jaxb-xjc.jar.
The changes I made was :
Driver.DateFormat = aaaa.MM.gg (original) to Driver.DateFormat = yyyy/MM/dd (new) and
Driver.TimeFormat = hh:mm:ss a z (original) to Driver.TimeFormat = HH:mm:ss (new)
With those changes I was able to generate the classes as needed.
HTH
Flavio

Answer (score 0):

I have same error generating java objects form command line xjc.bat. You can solve adding option `-no-header`

Answer (score -1):

I might guess that one of your xsd files have a regexp-based restriction attached to a type/element. Have you validated those files?