# JaxB automatic parsing from XML to Java classes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am new about jaxb. My question is the following: using jaxb, is it possible to do automatic mapping from an xml file to a java object? 
Starting from xml file, is there something generate the Java class with annotations jaxb relaitve?

Comment: You'll need an XSD, not just the XML. Look into [`xjc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html).

Comment: How do I generate an xsd file? You can do this automatically?

Comment: It is possible to infer an XSD from a number of example XMLs. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16397009/851811). However, it might be safer to have the real XSD, or design it yourself if you know the structure.

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed possible. However, you'll need an XSD rather than an XML file. There are tools out there ([Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html), for instance) that can infer an XSD from one or more example XML files.

Take into account that generating this XSD with a tool might get you inaccurate results if the XML sample isn't complete, or if the schema can't be fully represented in a single XML file (exclusive elements, etc).

Once you have an XSD, use [`xjc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html) in order to generate the marshaller/unmarshaller classes.

```
xjc myxsd.xsd
```

This will generate the annotated classes that JAXB will use for marshalling/unmarshalling. Notice you could also have coded these classes yourself. Once you have them, just use them  in your code:

```
File file = new File("myFile.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyRootElement.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
MyRootElement element = (MyRootElement) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have another problem. While do xjc myxsd.xsd i have this exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'g' 
What does it mean?

Comment: There seems to be a [related bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-915?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab) with JAXB 2.2.6 and affecting specifically the italian locale. It seems that it is fixed in 2.2.7. You might also find this question useful: [cannot generate classes with JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10757211/851811).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `JAXB` automatically does `marshalling` and `unmarshalling` but it requires a schema file.
JaxB is used to bind XML with Java objects. Using the `XSD` schema file, it does marshalling and unmarshalling. There are few simple ant tasks like XJC that can be used.

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) implementations only require an XML schema if you want to generate Java classes.  If you are starting from Java classes then an XML schema is not required.