# Error binding XML schema in JAVA (with JAXB)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I try to make a binding from XML schema to Java with JAXB following:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jaxb.html

Unfortunately, following those instruction, i note this error. Instead, i have follwed some helpful links like this ([cannot generate classes with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757211/cannot-generate-classes-with-jaxb)) but it doesn't still work.

What i have to do?

I use Netbeans 7.2.1, jdk 6.11 and Ubuntu 13.10 saucy os (for business specific)

Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'g'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:751)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:558)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:483)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getPrologComment(Options.java:924)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.createCodeWriter(Options.java:909)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.createCodeWriter(Options.java:899)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task._doXJC(XJC2Task.java:523)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task.doXJC(XJC2Task.java:454)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task.execute(XJC2Task.java:379)
at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:103)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Comment: The error is very specific: Some date format isn't correct. Post the XML in question.

Comment: is that of the netbeans example (http://www.netbeans.org/files/documents/4/2518/CreditReportSimple.wsdl)

Comment: Do you use binding customization?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm ushering in this technology for a few days and the only thing that I have followed is that netbeans guidelines that you could see in the link mentioned in my question

Comment: JAXB allows to customize automatic bindings (e.g. change element names in generated code, use other classes than default, set read/write custom methods, a.s.o. with extra customization XML file), but it looks like you don't use it. I was suspecting incorrect `SimpleDataFormat` pattern. Exception says 'g' is invalid pattern character and indeed `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't have it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html --- however 'G' is okay.

Comment: ok i understand the question, but what i have to do? what i have to fix (my xml, netbeans..)?